# when i invoke waitForTransactionReceipt in web3py, there's a alarm panic,and exit process

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

my code is

```
tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(txhash_ChaitinRouter,timeout=240)
```

when python3 run here.
there's a long time to wait
and sometime its going to this error

```
[1]    57250 alarm      python3 ethbot.test.py
```

and the transaction send success，what's going on?

Comment: Depending on the used gas price, Ethereum transactions might take up to 30-60 minutes, so your timeout might be too low.

Comment: Q_Q; i deploy it on ropsten. so that gasprice needn't so high?

Comment: You are correct. You can verify how long it takes for a transaction to go through on Etherscan.

Comment: ok thank u, i will try it.

Comment: would u mind "Answer my Question",with blue button below comment part?

Comment: There is no answer to your question yet. If you have figured out the answer yourself, please write it yourself.

Comment: so that i can show my thank gratitude by giving like